# A way to change Click's default help option?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

Whenever you create a command or group with Click, there's a default `--help` option to bring the usage guide:

```py
import click

@click.command()
def main():
    click.echo('Success!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I run the file with the `--help`, I should get:

```bash
$ python file.py --help
Usage: file.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
--help  Show this message and exit.
```

Now, Click allows you to override how the `help` option is called through the terminal via a parameter in the decorator:

```py
@click.command(
    context_settings=dict(
        help_option_names=['-f', '--foo']
    )
)
def main():
    click.echo('Success!')
```

```bash
$ python file.py -f
Usage: file.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
-f, --foo  Show this message and exit.
```

However, rummaging through Click's [documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/?highlight=help_option_names#click.Context), I don't see a similar option to override the default help *message*.

---

Is there a parameter to specify to `click.command` that overrides the text **"Show this message and exit"** when calling for help in the terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change click's default help option with the [`help_option`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/#click.help_option) decorator

#### Sample Code:

```py
@click.command(add_help_option=False)
@click.help_option('--foo', '-f', help='Show my better message and exit')
def main():
    """The docstring is the Help Message"""
    click.echo('Success!')
```

#### Test Code:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    print('-----------')
    cmd = 'main --foo'
    print('> ' + cmd)
    main(cmd.split())
```

#### Test Results:

```
Click Version: 8.1.3
Python Version: 3.7.8 (tags/v3.7.8:4b47a5b6ba, Jun 28 2020, 08:53:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> main --foo
Usage: test_code.py [OPTIONS]

  The docstring is the Help Message

Options:
  -f, --foo  Show my better message and exit
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing help text only a one-line [`help_option`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/#click.help_option) decorator is sufficient

```py
@click.help_option('--help', help='Show my better message and exit')
```

Alternatively you can follow the full [@Stephen Rauch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72581119/4504504)'s answer to tweak it in details